# Outlook 2007 Contact/Email

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook-2007, address-book

I have several contacts saved with photos. The photos do not appear in email messages I received from these folks. How can I make it so these pictures appear when they send me email messages? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

While we are on an Exchange server, I don't believe it matters.  Within Outlook, I simply click on the empty picture and choose a file.

Then in preview pane or the email itself when opened, I see the picture to the right of the address information.

How are you attaching the pictures to the contacts?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the email address matches what was sent to you, the picture will show up in the email.  Check the email address that you have saved for the person in your contacts folder.

Also, check to make sure that the contacts are stored in the default contacts folder.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth right clicking your contact folder and tick the box to use as an outlook address book if it isnt already. By default it should be